# middleware code isn't asynchronous? nodejs express

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, backend

So I am playing with node.js and express.js...

My nodejs code was given below.
In the '/' route it will send an html with one text inputfield and a submit button.

And you will see two middleware functions below that I want to run asynchronously

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080
const test = express()

test.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
test.use(bodyParser.json());
test.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

test.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send(`
        <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>test</title></head><body>
        <form class="loginform" action="/jump" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Your Name" required><br>
            <input type="submit" name="guest-login" value="test" id="guest-login">
        </form></body></html>
    `)
})

test.post('/jump', async (req,res)=>{
    req.session.username = req.body.username;
    req.session.loggedin = true;

    try{
        await first(req)
        await second(req,res)
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
})

test.listen(PORT,function(){
    console.log('listening on port : '+PORT)
})

function first(req){
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        for(let i=0; i<50000; ++i){
            console.log(req.session.username)
        }
        console.log('loop done')
        resolve()
    })
}

function second(req,res){
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        res.send(`<h1>WELCOME ${req.session.username}</h1>`)
        console.log(`DONE ${req.session.username}`)
        resolve()
    })
}
```

my problem was whenever I tried to do different post request (click submit) to different browser eg.(chrome and firefox) at roughly the same time, the node runtime was displaying the username of the browser that I have clicked "first", then it will output the next one sequentially... see example below

ex:

```
firefox
firefox
.
.
.
firefox
firefox
loop done
DONE firefox

chrome
chrome
.
.
.
chrome
chrome
loop done
DONE chrome
```

The above example was not the output that Im expecting.

In my understanding... the output that I was expecting was something like the code below... what am I doing wrong here?

```
firefox
chrome
chrome
firefox
chrome
firefox
chrome
loop done
firefox
loop done
DONE chrome
DONE firefox
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NodeJS is single-threaded, non-blocking I/O, here actually the single thread is busy printing on the console inside the loop it is not actually blocked. If the loop contains an async task like disk I/O, REST calls, or any async tasks the thread will start processing the other request and will return back with the result when the async task is done.

Answer (score 0):

`Javascript` only has 1 thread and in the `for` loop you blocked [`event loop`](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/). Because of this, any other code was not executed.

Node.js works great if you don't do complex calculations.

If you need to do complex calculations, then as a solution to this problem you can look at the materials on [`clusters`](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) and [`worker threads`](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html).

For a better understanding of the event loop, I can recommend that you watch the [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) on this topic